# Uninstall apparently hidden Windows Updates

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update, flash

I need to uninstall some Flash updates which left me unable to debug the Flex application I'm working on.

I went to the updates history in Windows Update and got the KB numbers of those updates, but that view doesn't let me uninstall, just check details. From the installed updates view I can uninstall updates, but those KB numbers or the update names do not appear.

I checked in the Microsoft site for those specific KB numbers and they instruct to run the independent installer with an argument (`/x` and `/uninst`) but that `.exe` seems to ignore the argument and install it again.

How can I uninstall those updates?

```
KB3001237
KB3004150
KB3079777
KB3087916
```

Comment: They've most likely been superseded by newer updates, or are prerequisites for other updates.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3001237 does not mention an "/x" argument, but it recommends to use "/uninstall /kb:<KB number>" - might be worth a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual problem was that even though I passed the argument to uninstall, the software kept telling me it was installing, but it was really uninstalling. I attribute that to the fact that I'm using Windows in Spanish and the translation is probably not right. It worked by just uninstalling KB3087916.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot uninstall windows updates from the windows updates screen. They appear in the `Programs and Features` in your `Control Panel`.

From there, click `View Installed Updates`. This screen will allow you to uninstall the windows updates you wish.